# How can I check which of the two radio button is checked in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, radio-button

How can I check which of the two radio button is checked in javascript/jquery in order to get the value of the input considering the fact that, in the HTML, both of them are by default unchecked (no **checked** attribute is added)

```
<input type="radio" name="AS88" value="true" required>
<input type="radio" name="AS88" value="false">
```

The following code does not work:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("AS88");
for (var i=0, len=elements.length; i<len; ++i) {
    if (elements[i].checked) {
        alert(elements[i].value)
    } 
};
```

**EDIT:**

Solutions with `:checked` in jquery such as:

```
$('input[name="AS88"]:checked').val();
```

always return **undefined**

Comment: you have to capture it on `change()` event of the radio button.

Comment: Sounds like a timing issue. Are you sure you're not executing the code before those inputs exist?

Comment: the code is executed just before the submit so all the input already exist

Comment: You say "both of them are by default unchecked", so unless the user actually clicks one of them both will remain in the unchecked state and your code (with or without jQuery) will not find a checked one.

Comment: I use **required** so the user is forced to select the option before the submit...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) along with [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector) and [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of the checked input element with name `AS88`

```
$('input[name="AS88"]:checked').val()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RxcKD/)

Comment: This always returns **undefined**

Comment: @GigiGammino if none of the radios are checked then it will return undefined

Comment: @GigiGammino check the attached jsfiddle

Comment: it works fine on fiddle but the same code (except for the click function) returns undefined for me!

Comment: that means the selector `$('input[name="AS88"]:checked')` is wrong

Comment: @GigiGammino can you try an alert `alert($('input[name="AS88"]').length)`

Comment: the alert for the length returns 0

Comment: @GigiGammino can you check the name of the radio buttons.. looks like it is not matching